# Can a Current class be overwritten by a new request before the previous one was finished?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can the attributes of a Current class as implemented in the [documentation of ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CurrentAttributes.html) be overwritten by a new request before the previous one was finished?

If a rails server can parse requests in parallel, either some strong mitigation mechanism should be in place, or a new request could override the state of the Current class. This would result in flawed data.

For example let's suppose we have the following controller actions:

```
def process_data
  processor = DataProcessor.new
  if processor.call_long_data_processing
    processor.log("#{Current.user} called data processing")
  end
end

def irrelevant_action
  render plain: 'hello'
end
```

If a user calls the slow `process_data` action, and before it is complete another user calls the fast `irrelevant_action` that would overwrite the attributes of the `Current` class. Which would lead log registering that the second user called data processing.

Puma supports some kind of concurrency, and other web servers probably do too. Can the kind of scenario described in the example happen in real life? If not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes` - Abstract super class that provides a **thread-isolated** attributes singleton.

This means no, other requests can't affect attributes of the current request.

> If a user calls the slow `process_data` action, and before it is complete another user calls the fast `irrelevant_action` that would overwrite the attributes of the `Current` class.

If you have one worker thread (or otherwise all workers are busy), the fast action sits in the queue and waits until there is an available worker. If you have several worker threads and there is a vacant one, fast request is taken by that vacant thread. Again, this does not interfere with any active requests.